# Cant login with Neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have installed neo4j on an EC2 instance and given port and access permissions to connect to it with chrome browser on my local machine.
The database is fluently accessible when I run db access codes on EC2, through py2neo. But when I open database using EC2-IP:7474 on my local chrome, I get to access the neo4j browser, but it does not let me login through. It always throws the error `ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection in 5000ms`

The credentials are correct. They are the same with which I access the database from EC2. Screenshot attached. What can be possible reason for this and workaround to solve this issue?[image]

I have gone through configuration file to uncomment lines such as

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

But the problem persists.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: HI Naman...
Could not solve the browser issue. Instead I am using REST API on my neo4j server through POST requests and retrieving results on postman. Your URL should be http://domain:7474/db/data/cypher. In 'Authorization' section, select 'Basic Auth', put your neo4j username and password. Then in the 'Header' section, put 'Content-Type': 'application/json' and finally in the 'Body' section, select "raw" and put your cypher query, eg {"query":"match (d:dep{name:'dabba'})-[rel:resides_in]-->(b:buildingl{name:'h_r_kadim'})\nreturn d,rel,b"}

Answer (score 3):

This happened to be because I had opened port 7474 on the ec2 instance, but not the bolt port 7687.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open this port 7687